# Error sending a file using Django - file turns out empty

Tags: django, python-3.x, response, httpresponse

This is my `views.py` files:

```
from django.http import HttpResponse

def render(request):
    response = HttpResponse(content_type='application/pdf')
    response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="somefilename.pdf"'
    response['X-Sendfile'] = '/files/filename.pdf'
    # path relative to views.py
    return response
```

When I run the server and request

```
http://localhost:8080/somestring
```

I get an empty file called `somefilename.pdf`. I suspect that there is some crucial part missing in `render`.

The other parts of this app outside of `views.py` are correct to my understanding.

Comment: Are you using `manage.py runserver`? It doesn't support `X-Sendfile`. In production, you need to enable X-Sendfile for your server (e.g. Apache).

Comment: @Alasdair, yes I am using `python manage.py runserver` to start the server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the code that solved my problem:

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
from wsgiref.util import FileWrapper

def render(request): 
    response = HttpResponse(FileWrapper(open('file.pdf', 'rb')), content_type='application/pdf')
    response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="somefilename.pdf"'

    return response
```

Answer (score 0):

The `manage.py runserver` development serer doesn't support X-Sendfile. In production, you need to enable X-Sendfile for your server (e.g. Apache).

You may find the [`django-sendfile`](https://github.com/johnsensible/django-sendfile) package useful. It has a backend that you can use in development. However, it hasn't had a release in some time, and I found that I had to apply [pull request 62](https://github.com/johnsensible/django-sendfile/pull/62) to get Python 3 support.